# Problem with the row count transform

Tags: ssis

I currently deployed an SSIS package (Developed on the 2005 version) (developed on my local server) in a pre production environment for testing. I have used the Row count transform to get a count of good/bad records. It works fine on my local system . However when i deploy this on the pre prod server, the row count does not work! (as in it does not recognize the vairbales i have assigned to the relevant transofm - no drop down abvaliable in the variables attribute part. tried deleting and adding a new transoform.. no luck.

Strangely this does not work for any of the other packages also present/deployed on the same server (tried this out by dropping an rc tramsform onto an existing package... same problem)

Any suggestions?

Thanks a tonne

Answer (score 1):

If you are having problem with the row count transform, another alternative that we use here at my company is creating a script component and incrementing a rowcnt variable by one. The performance is just as good-just add this code:

Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()

MyBase.PostExecute()

Me.Variables.rowcnt = Me.Variables.rowcnt + 1

End Sub

Comment: Hi rfonn thanks for this. I did a check and found that the SQL server release version was RTM and did not have any service pack installed. The minimum req for this control to work is SP1. i requested the folks to upgrade it to SP3. It should work now.Will keep updated.

Answer (score 1):

This certainly seems odd.  Are you saying that when you are in the **Advanced Editor for Row Count**, under **Custom Properties**, that the drop down beside **VariableName** has no options?  You should at least see all of the **System::** variables.

If the **User::** variables are not listed, my first suspicion is that they do not have the correct scope to be visible in the Data Flow Task where you have your RowCount.

When you go up to the Control Flow, and get the Variables list, do you see your user variable there?  What is the scope of it?

Note that I recognize that none of this fits with "it works locally but doesn't work when copied to the server", but it is at least where I would start...

Comment: The scrope is package. I did a check and found that the SQL server release version was RTM and did not have any service pack installed. The minimum req for this control to work is SP1. i requested the folks to upgrade it to SP3. It should work now.Will keep updated.